# ¿Como crear ventana sin bordes en PySide?

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyside

Tengo el siguiente codigo en PySide en maya :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
import shiboken

def getMayaWindow():
    pointer = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtGui.QWidget)


class MainWindowUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    parent = getMayaWindow()
    def __init__(self,  parent=parent):
        super(MainWindowUI, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # layout
        QVlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(QVlayout)

        #check for open Window first
        wnName = "WindowTest01"
        if cmds.window(wnName, exists =1):
            cmds.deleteUI(wnName, wnd=True)


        self.setObjectName(wnName)
        self.setWindowTitle("WindowTest01")
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent; border-radius: 100px;")

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setMinimumSize(560,800)
        self.setMaximumSize(560,800)        
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)    

        self.show()

class TabsMaker():
    pass



class buttonsMaker():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    MainWindowUI()
```

Necesito que la ventana este sin bordes, y ajustar la trasnparencia, cuando lo hago me carga una pantalla con las medidas de las establecidas pero con todo distorcionado por dentro, sin poder moverla, sin boton de cerrar. como puedo lograr esto ?.

Comment: He editado la pregunta eliminando las referencias a PyQt ya que son dos frameworks distintos (PyQt y PySide) aunque ambos se basen en Qt. No he usado nunca Maya pero por el lado de Qt la bandera `FramelessWindowHint` crea una ventana sin bordes y sin barra de título (es decir, no tiene botones de cerrar, minimizar, maximizar, etc. La propia documentación dice: "Produces a borderless window. The user cannot move or resize a borderless window via the window system"

Comment: perdon primero que nada por el mal uso de Hashtags, soy un novice en esto, y entiendo he leido la documentacion, pero luego, no puedo mover la ventana ni interactuar con ella , simplemente el FramelessWindowHint , me muestra un rectangulo negro matte en todo el medio de la pantalla sin posibilidad a nada. algun link de referencia que me puedan facilitar ? gracias